# Are there infinitely many square numbers with increasing digits?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

This is a question that came up while joking around with my friends, but now I am really intrigued by this question.

For sake of brevity, let's call square numbers with monotone increasing digits *peculiar squares*. Some examples of peculiar squares are $13^2 = 169$ (since $1 \leq 6 \leq 9$) and $15^2 = 225$. Question is, are there infintely many peculiar squares?

To tackle this question, I came up with a more generalized conjecture:

> **Peculiar Square Conjecture.** For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists only finitely many peculiar squares in base $n$.

I first tried solving for $n=2$. This was pretty easy, since it is equivalent to proving that there are only finitely many squares of form $11\cdots 1_{(2)}$.

Then I tried solving for $n=3$. Simple number theory shows that $11\cdots 122 \cdots 2_{(3)}$ cannot be a square number. Thus, we only need to show that there are finitely many squares of form $11\cdots 1_{(3)}$.  This was much easier said than done, and in the end I had to borrow the power of StackExchange. ([Integer solutions of $3^n-1=2m^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826307/integer-solutions-of-3n-1-2m2))

So up to this point, I know that the Peculiar Square Conjecture holds for $n = 2$ and $n = 3$, but I don't have clear idea of how to prove it for $n = 4$ or beyond. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156462/prove-that-16-1156-111556-11115556-1111155556-are-squares)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Show that in base $10$, all the numbers
$$37^2, \ 337^2, \  3337^2, \ 33337^2, \ 333337^2, ...$$

are "peculiar squares".

Comment: Wow... How do you come up with such intuition?

Comment: It also works with a $5$ at the end, look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580745/n-underbrace111-1-n-space-times-space-underbrace222-2-n1-s/3580783#3580783

Comment: @zwim Thank you, I will check it out!

Comment: @Dimen Not sure where I saw it for the first time, but I "knew" this pattern. The link provided by zwim, however, explains why it works.